# Where can you check the health / sync status of Mint repo mirrors?

Tags: linux-mint, package-management, repository

Is there something similar to that of [Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) and [Manjaro](https://repo.manjaro.org/) that shows the sync status of [Mint repo mirrors](https://www.linuxmint.com/mirrors.php)?

I am also open to creating my own script / utility to do the same if feasible, but don't know where to start.